# DL385 G2 powering off after some time

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I have one DL385 G2 server that since Thursday is not able to power on properly. I can't figure out what's the problem, since there is no indication neither in iLO 2 log, IML, nor any red/amber LED on the front panel. Sometimes it can boot to the OS, sometimes it power of after few seconds. I've tried swapping the CPUs, also backup CPU and memory, switching the PSUs, but nothing helps. After I press power button, it is green, after some random time it's  dark, fan run full speed for about 1 second, and then power off and power button is amber. Thank you very much for your help and insight.

Comment: My guess is a toasted mainboard. You could get lucky if you bought 5 year support on it, have you tried calling HP?

Comment: Isn't G2 even older than that? I'd say upgrade to G8. The power saving due to no longer using scsi drives is already worth it.

Comment: Hi Pauska, thank you for your response. I've tried calling HP and they've said it's out of warranty, more than 5 years, so if it's mainboard, I could try to find some on eBay. Can this behavior be cause also by bad PSUs?

Comment: The DL385 G2 was introduced in 2006. THey didn't really make it out into the field until 2007. From a technology perspective, it's similar to the first-runs of the G5 Intel ProLiants. So it has P400-era Smart Array controllers and SAS/SATA drives.

Comment: Hello Dennis, thank you for the suggestion, this piece is probably from March 2008.

Comment: @PeterDian You *could* get another system board, but it's far easier to buy another of the same unit if you intend to keep this server for some time. They're inexpensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is an older [ProLiant DL385 G2 server](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=worldwide&type=html&docid=12565)... 2006/2007 or so...

I'd suspect system board. Due to the age of the system and the fact that it's probably not under contract or support, you'll probably need to go the [used parts](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p3984.m570.l1313.TR9.TRC1.A0.Xdl385%20g2.TRS0&_nkw=dl385%20g2&_sacat=0&_from=R40) route to outfit this system. Another thing to try is the motherboard battery. When the system powers off then boots all the way, is the time correct?

Have you run a diagnostic CD/DVD?

You should reference the [**HP ProLiant DL385 Generation 2 Server Maintenance and Service Guide**](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00778876/c00778876.pdf) for parts information if you choose to self-support.

If you intend to troubleshoot this unit, follow the diagnostic flowchart outlined in the **[HP ProLiant Servers Troubleshooting Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00300504/c00300504.pdf)**.

Personally, I would not spend much time troubleshooting a server this far out of production. If you just need something that works quickly and intend to keep this system alive for awhile, buy another DL385 G2 system on eBay. They're under $200US. This ensures that you'll have some parts available for cannibalizing and is a quick fix. Long-term, prepare to move to a more current platform.

I *do* have two DL385 G2's still in production, though.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for help, basically I've tried everything I was able to find on support pages, including the diagnostics dvd. The battery is relatively new (about 1 year) and the time is correct after power off. One time, I was able to run diagnostic and tried quick and complete test, 7 loops and all was green, no problems found. The thing is, sometimes it runs for 5 minutes (max), sometimes it can't even complete POST.

Comment: The ILO2 log would be key here. Remember, the ILO stays alive even when the server is powered off. Check the time/date and see if the ILO2 reports something like, ***"Server power removed"*** in the logs.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the following in the iLO2 log: 
Informational iLO 2 07/13/2013 21:04 07/13/2013 21:04 1 Server power removed. 

Caution iLO 2 07/13/2013 21:04 07/13/2013 21:04 1 Server reset. 

Informational iLO 2 07/13/2013 21:02 07/13/2013 21:02 2 Server power restored.

Comment: K. Then it's the LED panel or the system board. Just get another unit so you don't waste the time.

Comment: I'm from Slovakia, so I will need to find one somewhere here, since the shipping from US is pretty high:):):) Anyway, thank you for your help, really appreciate it:)

Answer (score 1):

hp dl385 g2 have very unreliable power supplies.  We have several hundred of them, and have about fifty blown power supplies.

If you have two power supplies installed it will keep running on one only, with the other showing orange fault on the front control panel.

We haven't tried any with a single power supply, but I'd imagine they just die.

You could easily be swapping to an equally faulty power supply.